# r: condense x-axis in ggplot2 (x-axis is binary value)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

looking at some nfl data.. I am looking to condense my x axis.. my x value is binary.. so I only want to see 0 or 1 yet values in between 0 and 1 are appearing.. so I am seeing .25, .50, .75 and it is just taking up space.. how can I eliminate these unwanted values? thank you

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(gtgruns, aes(x=shotgun, y=epa)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image: shows unnecessary ".25, .50, .75" x axis values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example of your dataset, I can't test it but you should use `scale_x_continuous`:

```r
ggplot(gtgruns, aes(x=shotgun, y=epa)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,1))
```

Alternatively, if your `shotgun` variable is only composed of 0 and 1, you can pass them as factor:

```r
ggplot(gtgruns, aes(x=as.factor(shotgun), y=epa)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) + 
  theme_classic()
```